# Send commands from file to a server - robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I have a question related to RobotFramework, more exactly reading a file, grep it for different commands, add them to a dictionary and then send them commands to a server.

Let me show you what do I have now.

I have the second function called **Send commands from file to server**

```
Send commands from file to server
    [Arguments]  ${COMMANDS_FILE}
    ${FILE_CONTENT}=  Get File  ${COMMANDS_FILE}
    @{LINES}=  Split to Lines  ${FILE_CONTENT}
    : FOR  ${line}  IN  @{LINES}
    \  Send command  ${line}
```

Send command is a keyword that works fine, just sends commands to the server.

The commands file looks something like this (commands.txt):

```
  VAL1;VAL2;VAL3;
  VAL1;VAL4;VAL5;
  VAL6;VAL7;VAL8
  VAL6;VAL7;VAL8
```

So as you can see VAL1 is the same on both rows.

**How can I get VAL1 and save it somewhere (dict or list) and then run all commands from file that contains VAL1?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to further split each line - on the `;`, and check is the first command the one you look for. Here's how based on your code:

```
Send commands from file to server
    [Arguments]  ${COMMANDS_FILE}
    ${FILE_CONTENT}=  Get File  ${COMMANDS_FILE}

    @{LINES}=  Split to Lines  ${FILE_CONTENT}
    ${commands to run}=     Create List  # will store only the commands you want to run
    :FOR    ${line}  IN  @{LINES}
        \   ${members}=      Split String     ${line}     separator=;    # each command in the line is a list member now
        \   Run Keyword If      $members[0] == 'VAL1'       Append To List      ${commands to run}      ${line}

    :FOR    ${command_line}     IN      @{commands to run}
    \   Send Command  ${command_line}
```

Comment: Hello Todor. I think I asked my question wrong. More exactly, I want to check if VAL1 exists in file, and if yes run all commands(full line including val 2;val3; and val4 val5) that contains VAL1, in the example above:VAL1;VAL2;VAL3;
  VAL1;VAL4;VAL5;

Comment: @Manfeld - let me see if I understand you correctly: you want to 1st) gather all commands which are on lines starting with VAL1, and then 2nd) send them all appended with "; " - i.e. as a chained bash command? For the 2nd, that thing to send should be called once, but the argument should have all commands from all lines?

Comment: So if yes, the current version will send `VAL1;VAL2;VAL3;`, then will send `VAL1;VAL4;VAL5;`, but you want just one `Send Command` execution, and it has to have the argument `VAL1;VAL2;VAL3;VAL4;VAL5;`

Comment: Hello Todor, yes it's ok the first answer. But one more question, I thought this way. I will save VAL1;VAL2;VAL3 in a list(using Get Matches with regexp) and then I will append this list to a dict. Can I do that? For example dict { 'key_value': 'VAL1;VAL2;VAL3'
                                           'VAL1;VAL4;VAL5'
and I will send key_value to the server.

Comment: You could that, quite easily - with `Create Dictionary` and then `Set To Dictionary` with the items. Yet, using a dict looks quite cumbersome - what's the point in that? And to get the value you've pasted in the comment, you have to combine all rows in a single string.

Comment: @Manfeld This is how to combine all the values in the list, to a single string - I'd suggest you just pass it to `Send Command`, but you can also add it to a dict, if you really want to. Anyways, here it is - `${commands string}=      Catenate    SEPARATOR=;${space}     @{commands to run}`; the SEPARATOR must be with capital letters, and this will add a space after the `;` character (just in case). This comments go quite off the original question :)